# Flask app conflicting routes is it the routes. any ideas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pythonanywhere

I am trying to make a forum or code sharing like site on pythonanywhere using a flask app, but I have conflicting routes so it fails.

What this is doing is adding a new line to a .csv file (that already exists) when the user completes and html form I have set up. This works fine on the /addpythoncode route, but it fails on the /addflaskcode route.

I will provide the routes and the error log output below. Can someone please help me fix this?

```py
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import random
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/addpythoncode', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addpycode():
  if request.method == 'GET':
      return render_template('addpythoncode.html')
  else:
      dict = {}
      dict["codename"] = request.form['codename']
      dict["name"] = request.form['name']
      dict["code"] = request.form['code']
      f = open("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/Pythonforum.csv", "a")
      with f:
          fnames = ['codename', 'name', 'code']
          writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fnames)
          writer.writerow(dict)
          return redirect('http://ethankbdca.pythonanywhere.com/pythonforum')

@app.route('/addflaskcode', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newflskcode():
  if request.method == 'GET':
      return render_template('addflaskcode.html')
  else:
      dict = {}
      dict["routename"] = request.form['routecode']
      dict["name"] = request.form['name']
      dict["routecode"] = request.form['routecode']
      f = open("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/Flaskforum.csv", "a")
      with f:
          fnames = ['routename', 'name', 'routecode']
          writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fnames)
          writer.writerow(dict)
          return redirect('http://ethankbdca.pythonanywhere.com/flaskforum')
```

Here is the message I get on the error log:

```
2019-03-26 21:21:43,161: OSError: write error
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190730/discussion-on-question-by-ethan-koehlerbryant-i-am-hosting-a-forum-site-made-wit).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree with Milad M., but I agree with you that there is no such mistake.
Change the indentation level of return render_template (...). Add a try-except block to the code where the file is written to.

```
import abort 

@app.route('/addpythoncode', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addpycode():
  if request.method == 'GET':
      return render_template('addpythoncode.html')
  else:
      dict = {
          'codename': request.form['codename'], 
          'name': request.form['name'], 
          'code': request.form['code'], 
      }
      try:
          fnames = ['codename', 'name', 'code']
          f = open("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/Pythonforum.csv", "a")
          writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fnames)
          writer.writerow(dict)
          writer.close()
      except Exception as ex:
          abort(500)
      return redirect('http://ethankbdca.pythonanywhere.com/pythonforum')
```

This should cause an Internal Server Error on read-write problems.

Comment: So i want an error why?

Comment: anyway the python route works but wether or not i use your code or mine it fails for the flask section

Comment: @EthanKoehlerBryant Please don't hassle people to contact you on third-party platforms. Thanks.

Comment: So anyway did you understand the problem when I explained it?

Comment: @BaummitAugen  please remove this question from on hold. I am trying to get help debugging my code. This particular problem has been bugging (really not trying to make a pun there) me for days.

Comment: @EthanKoehlerBryant When you edit it to include an MCVE as requested, it will be reviewed for re-opening by domain experts. But first you should fix it up a bit, as I said.

Comment: @BaummitAugen how long should it take?

Comment: @EthanKoehlerBryant The reviewers had a look at it, but apparently they still did not like it. (1 voted to reopen, 3 voted to leave it closed.) Not being a domain expert here, I'm reluctant to overwrite their decision.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I updated the title as well. That will probably help

Comment: @EthanKoehlerBryant Good luck. If you need more guidance, please visit [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).